# Can you define an interface such that a class that implements it must contain a member that is also of that class?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance

Essentially what I want to do is impliment a class that can contain a list of references to instances of the same type. Something like the following:

```
interface IAccessibilityFeature
{
    List<IAccessibilityFeature> Settings { get; set; }
}

class MyAccess : IAccessibilityFeature
{
    List<MyAccess> Settings { get; set; }
}
```

I know this won't compile because the interface explicitly says my `Settings` must be of the type `List<IAccessibilityFeature>`. What I am after is some guidance as to the correct way to achieve what I'm trying to do in the `MyAccess` class.

Comment: Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwtft8ak(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Cheers Tom, interesting reading :)

Comment: Note that neither of the currently visible answers actually *require* that the implementing class provides *itself* as the type parameter T. It is ultimately up to you to enforce the strict requirement, the type system cannot do it for you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
interface IAccessibilityFeature<T> where T : IAccessibilityFeature<T>
{
    List<T> Settings { get; set; }
}

class MyAccess : IAccessibilityFeature<MyAccess>
{
    List<MyAccess> Settings { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This could be done with:

```
interface IAccessibilityFeature<T>
{
    List<T> Settings { get; set; }
}

class MyAccess : IAccessibilityFeature<MyAccess>
{
    List<MyAccess> Settings { get; set; }
}
```